# Way to convert java.hprof.txt to binary hprof format?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling, hprof

I have a java.hprof.txt file (automatically generated after an OutOfMemoryError) which I would like to convert to the binary hprof format. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't. You have to create it again as a binary hprof.